# Sorting dates in recyclerView from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hello friends

In the above database structure i wants to sort by date in ascending order and display in recyclerView. I used the below code, but its not working want i tries to achieve,

```
Query MyEventsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Workers Details").child(userID)
        .child("My Events").orderByChild("From_Date");

//Display events
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WorkerMyEvents> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WorkerMyEvents>()
                .setQuery(MyEventsRef, WorkerMyEvents.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
        = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WorkerMyEvents, WorkerMyEventViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WorkerMyEventViewHolder eventsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final WorkerMyEvents newEvents)
    {
        //Id with date and time key
        final String IDs = getRef(i).getKey();
        final String eventIDs = IDs.substring(0,18);

        final String serve = list3.get(i);

        NewEventsRef.child(eventIDs).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
```

So , I am expecting a best solution for this problem friends, And please give me a solution related to the above code. Thanks!

Comment: You should change the way you store the date. You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562375/9346054

Comment: No this is not suits for my problem , because the date's is not set as their posted event date , whereas the date's is chosen by the user , they may vary at any cost .

Comment: Don't store the dates as String values, store them as a longs as explained in my answer from the following.

Comment: I itself found the solution bro ..tqs ..by using string itself